# Why isn't Expression Blend 4 rendering my User Control? It's only showing XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I'm seeing the same issue as this post

[Why isn't Expression Blend rendering my User Control? It's only showing XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622647/why-isnt-expression-blend-rendering-my-user-control-its-only-showing-xaml)

But I'm using Blend 4 and VS 2010.  It's a WPF app.

I already had the ProjectTypeGuids (mentioned in that post) in my project file.

{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

I also ran Blend 4 SP1; but it didn't help.

I've tried using various versions of the target framework:
.NET Framework 4,
.NET Framework 4 Client Profile,
.NET Framework 4 Client Profile Platform Update 1,
.NET Framework 4 Platform Update 1

Ideas anyone?  thanks!

Also, I'm still trying to understand how to pose this question on this forum. (newbie here) Should a new question have been asked here (as I did) or should this question have been surfaced as an edit to someone else's answer on the referenced post?  I guess what's confusing me is that I don't see an "ask a follow up question" button.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3199423/921321) it might be a problem with build configurations if using multiple assemblies.

Comment: Have you tried commenting everything out except the most basic visual elements to see if anything will display?  Is it only your UserControl or do any of your windows/views display?

Comment: I tried commenting almost everything out...but it still doesn't display.  I noticed that there's also other things disabled such as Add New Item.  The project opens fine and builds in either Blend or VS.

Answer (score 0):

What is your platform target?  Blend generally wants to use AnyCPU.  Dropping down to a specific instruction set (x86 or x64, for example) makes Blend unhappy.